# How to create certificate from keystore.jks and truststore.jks files

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, jks

I need to authenticate with two-way authentication. I have two JavaKeyStore files keystore.jks and truststore.jks that I use when authentication with java client , now I want to use Python client that needs .cer file . so how can I create the certificate file from the jks files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command:

```
keytool -export -alias keystore_alias -file your_cert.cer -keystore keystore.jks
```

Here `keystore_alias` is the alias of the keystore.  You will prompted for the keystore password, which you also must know in order to generate a certificate.

This website is a great reference for the various things that can be done with Java keystore files:

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

Comment: Thanks , this command works for me :    keytool -export -alias selfsigned  -file your_cert.cer -keystore truststore.jks